# iPhone: how to detect when user clicks a button in a customized UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, button, sdk, uitableview, delegates

I have created a customized call that is called in `UITableViewCell (cellForRowAtIndexPath)`.  Everything worked great, but then I added a button (`UIButton`) to the cell.  The button's "Referencing Outlet" is the custom cell.

I cannot work out how to read when a user clicks the button.  Do I need to declare a delegate method in the header file containing the table or the customized cell header?

I tried the `- (void)buttonPressedAction:(id)sender {}` method, but it doesn't seem to be detecting when the button is pressed

I also tried:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

NSSet *aTouch = [event allTouches];
UITouch *touch = [aTouch anyObject];
CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.dashboardTable];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.dashboardTable indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];

NSLog(@"indexPath %@",indexPath);

}
```

but again, nothing registers when the button is clicked.  I tried adding UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to .h but no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the action of the button. If you do this is a XIB all you have to do is control click the button and then drag to the controller. This should give you a list of actions available to the button.

To do this in code you would use the - (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents method.

```
[myButton addTarget:myTargetController action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Hi Sosborn.  Is the code you mention above placed in the CustomCell's .h and .m, or in the class that calls (uses) the CustomCell?  What is confusing is that "myButton" works in the main class (table section), but the compiler complains when I add your new method above.  Very strange.

Comment: Ideally that code should be executed at the same time that you create the button. But, without knowing how everything is set up it is hard to tell you exactly what is right. You have to adapt it to your situation. What warning does the compiler give you?

Comment: So I edited the CustomCell and added this method : -(IBAction) clickButton: (id)sender {

    NSLog(@"clicked");

}.  I now get a log message each time the button is pressed (from the CustomCell class), but how do I know find the row number corresponding to a specific button being pressed? (from the class calling the CustomCell?)  I tried the addTarget but nothing happens Help appreciated.

Comment: int row = [myTableView indexPathForCell:self].row